# How can I number sections below subsection in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning

I want to make sections in LaTeX.

For a document with `chapter` divisions, one has

- 1.1 = section
- 1.1.1 = subsection
- 1.1.1.1 = subsubsection

What about 1.1.1.1.1?

What do I have to use to make lower-level sections be numbered as 1.1.1.1.1?

Comment: Are you writing an scientific work? If yes perhaps you rethink your document structure? If my students need so much numbered headings I ask them to rethink the structure. It is better not to have these deep numbers.

Answer (score 99):

You have to insert `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}` to your document preamble and then the command `\paragraph{title}` is the equivalent of what you mean by `\subsubsubsection{title}`.

But *in my opinion* is not a good idea to have numbered paragraphs nor numbered subsubsections. It makes the text much less readable.

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} % seting level of numbering (default for "report" is 3). With ''-1'' you have non number also for chapters
 %\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} % if you want all the levels in your table of contents
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title (depth 0)}
\section{section title (depth 1)}
\subsection{subsection title (depth 2)}
\subsubsection{subsubsection title (depth 3)}
\paragraph{paragraph title (depth 4)}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph title (depth 5)} % last existing level
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree it does not suit the guidelines of a well presented book, but it is absolutely mandatory for the technical documentation were I work :) so thank you ! :)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. It works in the main document, but the numbering does not appear in the table of content? is it possible to make it appear in the table of content (and therefore in the "side pane" of evince) as well?

Comment: Note that the default for the `report` class is currently 2 and not 3 (maybe this has changed in the past 10 years since this answer was written).

Comment: ...and if anyone is wondering why they can't get numbering beyond `1.1.1` in the `\tableofcontents`, it will only do more if you use `\documentclass{report}`