# Include sub subsection (paragraph) in the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, subsection

I know that it is unusual to use paragraphs as the fourth layer of depth. However, in my article, I also use paragraphs as subsubsubsection. Is there a way to also include all of the layers into the table of content?

This would be a simple example based on this question ([How can I number sections below subsection in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130795/how-can-i-number-sections-below-subsection-in-latex)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter title (depth 0)}
\section{section title (depth 1)}
\subsection{subsection title (depth 2)}
\subsubsection{subsubsection title (depth 3)}
\paragraph{paragraph title (depth 4)}
\subparagraph{Subparagraph title (depth 5)}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your suggestions!

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`

Comment: Yes, that answers it! Thank you very much!

Comment: There are no chapters in `article`. Use `report`. (or `book`)